# How to override an Enum class to return member value instead of member object?

Tags: python, enums, overriding

I have a enum class for shortcuts to common system paths:

```
    _HOME = str(Path().home())

    class Shortcuts(Enum):
        RECENTS = _HOME + '/Recents'
        DESKTOP = _HOME + '/Desktop'
        DOCUMENTS = _HOME + '/Documents'
        DOWNLOADS = _HOME + '/Downloads'
        APPLICATIONS = '/Applications'
        LIBRARY = '/Library'
        SYSTEM = '/System'
        USERS = '/Users'
        TRASH = _HOME + '/.Trash'
```

I want to be able to access members to where their value is returned instead of a member object.

```
    print(Shortcuts.RECENTS)
    > '/Users/username/Recents'
```

---

I've tried overriding the ***__getitem__***, ***__getattr___*** and ***__getattribute__*** superclass methods, but am getting errors just when implementing them without modification.

```
def __getattribute__(self, item): #type error: str obj not callable
    return item

def __getattribute__(self, item): #type error: str obj not callable
    return item.value

def __getitem__(self, item): #returns same object if item.value, item.name, ..etc
    return item
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you inheriting `Enum` again ? Looks like you don't need any `inheritance`

Comment: If all you want is a namespace, use a regular class.

Comment: You might want to override the `__str__` method: `def __str__(self): return self.value`.

Comment: @hansolo of course, I just started using Enum more regularly and forgot how obvious this is.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this by overloading the `__repr__` method like so:

```py
def __repr__(self):
   return self._value_
```

Comment: Ran into the same problem and this does not seem to work.

Comment: maybe you should redifine the `__str__` method instead